# Spelling mistake in Stack Exchange tool tip

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, network-profile, spelling

I see a spelling mistake in Stack Exchange [network profile page](https://stackexchange.com/users/2855348/arulkumar) accounts tab's tool tip. The "across" is displaying "accross" in the accounts tab.

But in reputation and activity tab the tool tip is correct. Screen shot for reference.

[image: Across not Accross]

Comment: Just in case somebody ends up confused for some reason (like me): You'll have to hover the cursor at those tabs to see that toast. The cursor is not visible in the screenshot. Hovering on accounts tab would show you the issue.

Comment: @Firelord: Usually the cursors wont visible when we take print screen option. Now I manually added those cursors. It is fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What? It's simply the less traditional two-'c' spelling of across. It comes from our uniccorn ancestors.

Anyway, about that. Turns out, it wasn't even the only place in our code with that spelling (although, the only user-facing instance). It's fixed now. Thanks for reporting it.

Comment: _It's simply the less traditional two-'c' spelling of across._ If so, then why the "accross" is not same on across the tool tips.

Comment: I suppose sarcasm doesn't always cross cultural boundaries... it was a joke.